# How to change the type of an @Input variable with an other chained decorator

Tags: angular, typescript-decorator

I would like to transform an @Input into a stream. This is what I mean:

```
data$ = new Subject<number[]>();
@Input() set data(value: number[]) {
    this.data$.next(value);
}
```

Works like a charm. Now I can use this stream everywhere in my code. But I was wondering if there is a way to simplify this, with a @Decorator for example:

```
@Input() @AsObservable() data: Observable<number[]>
```

even better

```
@Input('data') @AsObservable() data$: Observable<number[]>;
```

But now angular starts complaining about the `number[]>` vs `Observable<number[]>`

```
myNumbers = [1,2,3,4];
...
<app-my-foo [data]="myNumbers"></app-my-foo>
```

> Type 'number[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable': source, operator, lift, subscribe, and 2 more.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oib4v2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fas-observable.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ffoo%2Ffoo.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Is there a way to fix this issue with my decorator approach? Or should I go for a different approach, for example stick to the `ngOnChanges` lifecycle function? Any suggestions?

Update: Usage example:

```
@Component({ selector: 'app-foo', ... })
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() isBaz = false;
    @Input<number[]>('data') @asObservable<number[]>() data$: Observable<number[]>;
    @Input<boolean[]>('state') @asObservable<boolean[]>() state$: Observable<boolean[]>;

    ngOnInit() {
        combineLatest([this.data$, this.state$]).pipe(...).subscribe(...);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: `myNumbers = of([1,2,3,4])` check this one. You need to convert it as observable out of your number array.

Comment: Ideally I don't want to change the interface of that component, because that component is used around the world. It might break the internet :) I've added an example at the bottom of my post. This will explain the need of a stream!

Answer (score 0):

Using stream like `subject` is mostly use when you store something on the service, and you want all places to notify when it changed.
but here you're using `@Input` - meaning you're inside a component - so there's no need to use `subject` because the template will change every time you change the `@Input` value.
so I recommend you to store it as is - `@Input() data: number[]`

but if you need the stream for some reason - you can pass it from parent component like that:

```
myNumbers = of([1,2,3,4])
<app-my-foo [data]="myNumbers"></app-my-foo>
```

and in your child component:

```
@Input('data') @AsObservable() data$: Observable<number[]>;
```

good luck :)

Comment: Ideally I don't want to change the interface of that component, because that component is used around the world. It might break the internet :) I've added an example at the bottom of my post. This will explain the need of a stream!